# Help with having Windows 7 and Linux on one laptop HDD?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7

I would love to install Ubuntu but I don't want to lose Windows 7 SP1. I am really afraid to make a partition unless it's a fresh HDD with nothing on it.(new PC, etc) Anyone have a very detailed video or walkthrough?

Answer (score 0):

Try `wubi` the official ubuntu windows installer it will install ubuntu on a different partition or even just inside a folder and you're computer will be able to boot to it. The windows boot manager is conserved. More info here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a software like Partition Magic to create a separate partition. With it you can create partitions for the free space without losing your data, right from inside Windows. Then you can safely install Ubuntu. You only need about 8GB partition for Ubuntu.

Comment: So I download linux and install it to the partition not the HDD?

Answer (score 0):

I used LinuxLive USB Creator (www.linuxliveusb.com/‎) to create a bootable Ubuntu 13.04 USB Drive and installed alongside Windows via that method. I have a 500GB HDD and opted to split that in half, which can be easily done in the partition manager that is built into the installer. Had no issues with lost data and GRUB gives me the choice whether to boot into Ubuntu (default) or Windows.

Alternatively, you could partition the drive from within Windows & then run the Ubuntu installer. I prefer to use AOMEI Partition Assistant as it has a good GUI and (I feel) is beginner-friendly.

Unfortunately I can't find a good guide to help with the process, but the Ubuntu installer makes the whole thing very user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualBox or VMWare to create its virtual machine and can use it from there.